# Mysql ignore insert if foreign key fails

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I have the following query:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `article_comments` (`comment`, `user_id`, `parent_id`, `article_id`, `date`)
VALUES ('dddddddddddddddddddddd', 5, 9999, 102, '2016-03-13 17:42:19')
```

parent_id 9999 fails foreign key cause id with 9999 not exists. so I want when foreign key check fails just ignore insert and return 0 affected rows, but this code shows me error

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use php you can do something like this :

```
try{
$db->exec('INSERT IGNORE INTO `article_comments` (`comment`, `user_id`, `parent_id`, `article_id`, `date`)
VALUES ('dddddddddddddddddddddd', 5, 9999, 102, '2016-03-13 17:42:19')');
}
catch($e){}
```